# What is the C++ implicit linking DLL equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I use implicit linking when building C++ DLLs using .lib file. When I build DLL in C#, I don't see .lib creation. Hence, I want to know how to perform implicit linking in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET assemblies does not have concept of .lib files.

.NET references actual DLL files directly without any intermediate representation.